# Why aren't all games impartial games?

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

We can take any partisan game, like Chess, and make it into an impartial game like so:

Take the game tree of moves for both players and make each game state a spot on the board. Now we start the game with a piece starting at the "beginning" state. The rules are the same for both players, you may move the piece forward to any available space, and a player loses when they can no longer move.

This seems impartial to me. Both players can move on the board in the exact same way. The only difference is who goes first. So what is wrong with this example? What is the precise definition of what "symmetrical play" means?

Comment: Not following.  In Chess, each player can only move pieces of the right color.   In an impartial game, all moves should be available to whomever is moving.

Comment: @lulu The OP has essentially hard-coded that into their game. The issue is that the connection with chess is quite "unstable" and goes away when we think about combining games; see my answer.

Comment: the game you describe is symmetrical but it does not model chess! because if the black player in this game can no longer move it does not mean he got check mated in the game of chess, it could mean the white player is check mated.

Comment: the problem is that in the game tree the turn of players is encoded in the tree, so you either only allow the "right" player move at a given state which make the game assymetric or allow any player move at any state which create a diffrent game than chess.

Comment: @NoahSchweber  Ah, perhaps I am not clear what impartial means.  If we are in state $S$, then White can only transition to some "adjacent" stares, and similarly for Black.  The available next moves are not the same for each player.  Or have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have succeeded in producing an impartial game $I$ with the following property:

> Player $1$ has a winning strategy in $I$ iff player White has a winning strategy in Chess; similarly, player $2$ has a winning strategy in $I$ iff player Black has a winning strategy in Chess. Moreover, these bi-implications are witnessed by very simple "strategy translation" functions.

However, in combinatorial game theory equivalence of games is a finer notion than simply "same person should win." For example, the one-red-edge and the two-red-edges Hackenbush boards are each won by player Red, but they are not equivalent games. Your $I$ is not in fact equivalent to Chess in any deeper sense: for example, letting $+$ denote the usual [sum of games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_sum) we have by a general "mirroring" argument that $I+I$ is null but (assuming Chess is a win for White) Chess $+$ Chess is a win for White.

So basically, what we're seeing here is just further evidence that **we need to be careful in introducing a notion of "equivalence" for games**.

Comment: Ah I see. So what you're saying is that if you played two games of "simulated Chess" at a time, the white player could play the black player's moves, switching sides in a sense if the other player chose to skip a move in one game, since the game is symmetric. However, in two games of real chess there would be no such switching teams. If player 1 played on board 1 and player 2 played next on board 2, then player 1 would not be able to play black's turn on board 1, he would skip black's turn and play what would be white's second turn. Is this correct?